# Merging multiple orthophto tif to gpkg with gdalwrap - artefacts, transaprent background (nodata value)

Tags: r, tiff, gdal

I try to merging multiple orthophoto photos (tif format) into gpkg fromat for using in qfield app. I found some answer how to do this in R with package gdalUtils.

I used this part of code:

```
gdalwarp(of="GPKG",srcfile=l[1:50],dstfile="M:/qfield/merge.gpkg",co=c("TILE_FORMAT=PNG_JPEG","TILED=YES))
```

Process was succesfully finished but when I looked results I found some artefacts.

In a photo you see merged gpkg file with added layer of fishnet (tif lists) and artefacts. Artefacts looks like small parts of original list of tif which are reordered and probably also overlaped.

[image]
[image]
[image]

First I was thougth that there is some error in originall orthophoto tif. But then I created raster mosaic, raster catalog, merged tif to new tif dataset and  I also published raster catalog to esri server and created tpk file from them and artefacts did not show. Is problem my code? Thank you

Edit:
I found solution for my problem. If I create vrt then artefacts do not show so i used this code:

```
gdalbuildvrt(gdalfile = ll, output.vrt = "C:/Users/..../dmk_2017_2019.vrt")

gdalwarp(of="GPKG",srcfile="C:/Users/..../dmk_2017_2019.vrt",
         dstfile="C:/Users/..../dmk_2017_2019.gpkg")

gdaladdo(filename="C:/Users/..../dmk_2017_2019.gpkg",r="average",levels=c(2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256),verbose=TRUE)
```

I have another question. What to do to get transparent nodata value (background)?
[image]

I tried with - srcnodata=255 255 255 but this helped only that black background become white I tried also with argument dstalpha but without succes. In qgis its possible  this with setting transparenty:

[image]

Comment: looking at [old ticket comment 12](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5102) and [jpeg details](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/doc/source/drivers/raster/jpeg.rst) perhaps it has to do with some input jpegs being nodata most significant bit and others least significant bit and setting JPEG_MASK_BIT_ORDER. Still scratching around for a bit order test for the jpegs.

Comment: [lines 2493 to 2507](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/frmts/jpeg/jpgdataset.cpp) reveals the test criteria, raster width not multiple of 8, so `raster_width %% 8 == 0`and beginning and ending of lines end = 1 and next line begin = 1, then Frank's code properly assesses if it is Lease Signif Bit or Most Signif Bit, all this from a ticket from Evan Roualt 7 years ago and Evan is now maintainer.  So really no progress yet, but ... an inkling.